# ViewController is not getting released after being popped from navigation stack in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

I would like to assure people that I had gone through all the article over internet explaining memory leaks when using button to pop the controller from stack ,and I am aware of strong reference which UIButton creates while triggering events with Lambdas .

I had tried all that none seem to be working for me .

**Problem statement**

I have a UICollectionViewController as Root ViewController and a floating buttons on top of it which I have created programmatically and added as subviews.

These buttons push viewcontrollers in to stack .

here is the method where  I push the controller .

```
private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var button = sender as UIButton;
    var board = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    switch (button.Tag) { 

        case 3: { 
                var vc = board.InstantiateViewController("BibleViewController");
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
                vc = null;

                break;

            }
        case 5: { 
                var vc = board.InstantiateViewController("RecordingViewController");
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
                vc = null;

                break;
            }
        case 7: {  
                var vc = board.InstantiateViewController("CameraFbController");
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
                vc = null;

                break;
            }
        case 6: {
                var vc = board.InstantiateViewController("NewEmojiController");
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
                vc = null;

                break;
            }
        case 4: { 
                var vc = board.InstantiateViewController("WriteNShareController");
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);
                vc = null;
                break;
            }
        default : {
                break;
            }



    }
}
```

Assume I am pushing BibleViewController (Case 3:)

Please find the code for this controller

```
public partial class BibleHomeController : UIViewController
{
    IList<string> items;
    IList<string> item1;

    public BibleHomeController() : base("BibleHomeController", null)
    {
    }
    public BibleHomeController(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    ~BibleHomeController() { 

        Console.WriteLine("it was called ");

    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        LoadJson();

        tableView.DataSource = new BTableViewDataSource(items);
        tableView.Delegate = new TableDelegate(items,this);
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("BookCell",NSBundle.MainBundle),BookCell.Key);




    }
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        backBtn.TouchUpInside += HandleBackClick;
        nwBtn.TouchUpInside += newBtn;
        oldBtn.TouchUpInside += oldBtnHanle;
    }
    private void HandleBackClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
    }
    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        backBtn.TouchUpInside -= HandleBackClick;
        nwBtn.TouchUpInside -= newBtn;
        oldBtn.TouchUpInside -= oldBtnHanle;
                    backBtn = null;
        nwBtn = null;
        oldBtn = null;
        tableView = null;

    }
    private void newBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tableView.DataSource = new BTableViewDataSource(item1);
        tableView.Delegate = new TableDelegate(item1,this);
        tableView.ReloadData();
    }
    private void oldBtnHanle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tableView.DataSource = new BTableViewDataSource(items);
        tableView.Delegate = new TableDelegate(items,this);
        tableView.ReloadData();
    }
    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
    private void LoadJson() {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("BibleSection/BibleBooks/Books.json")) {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        }
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("BibleSection/BibleBooks/NewBook.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            item1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        }
    }

}
public class BTableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    IList<string> data;

    public BTableViewDataSource(IList<string> list) {

        data = list;
    }
    ~BTableViewDataSource() {
        Console.WriteLine("it was called ");
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // if cell is not available in reuse pool, iOS will create one automatically
        // no need to do null check and create cell manually
        var cell = (BookCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("BookCell", indexPath) as BookCell;
        cell.PopulateCell(data[indexPath.Row], "");
        cell.SetNeedsLayout();

        //cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            return cell;

    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {

        return data.Count;

    }


}
public class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate { 
    IList<string> data;
    BibleHomeController owner;
    public TableDelegate(IList<string> list, BibleHomeController reference)
    {
        owner = reference;
        data = list;
    }
    ~TableDelegate()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("it was called ");
    }
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);
        var board = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        var vc = (BibleChapterCollectionview)board.InstantiateViewController("BibleChapterCollectionview") as BibleChapterCollectionview;
        vc.itemName = data[indexPath.Row];
        owner.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, true);

    }

}
```

My problem is , when I pop the controller in BibleViewController , 
Destructor of none of the classes are called neither dispose is called thereby controller memory is not released .

so everytime i push and pop I add some memory to heap .

I would like to point out , I am detaching all the event handlers from button in viewDidDisappear method .

Could you please help me how to release the resources when I pop the controller .

EDIT : 
I had figured the problem is with the tableview.delegate and table.datasource lines.
if I comment them problem is solved .

Should I use weakDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying this part of code has worked for me .

```
private void HandleBackClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            tableView.Delegate = null;
            tableView.DataSource = null;
            tableView.Source = null;
        this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
    }
```

//below modification is not related to problem statement but was needed as buttons need not be nulled

```
 public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    backBtn.TouchUpInside -= HandleBackClick;
    nwBtn.TouchUpInside -= newBtn;
    oldBtn.TouchUpInside -= oldBtnHanle;


}
```